# How to shuffle a list of activities

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I'm working with a simple game. I want to shuffle a list of activities. When I press a button it will randomly pick an activity and load it using the start Activity intent. Is this possible? Where should i start? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

when i try to click the button, it forces to close.
here's what i've got so far

```
Button shuffle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

final ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<Class>(4);
activities.add(SampleTwo.class);
activities.add(SampleThree.class);
activities.add(SampleFour.class);
activities.add(SampleFive.class);


shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(activities.size());
        Intent i = new Intent(context, activities.get(random));
        startActivity(i);
        }

});
```

Comment: Do you need to shuffle the list or do you just want to pick a random activity from the list?

Comment: I want to randomly pick an activity from a list. Is it possible?

Comment: Absolutely, see my answer.

Comment: I want to create my list of activities using ArrayList and then i want to randomly pick an activity. Is there a way to include there a class file? ex. i have MainActivity.java, Menu.java and so on. I want to randomly call the class. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

To shuffle a list, you can use method `Collections#shuffle()`:

```
  Collections.shuffle(list);
```

if you just need to pick a random activity from the list I would do:

```
  if(list.size() > 0){
     list.get((new Random()).nextInt(list.size()));
  }
```

[`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) generates pseudorandom numbers, nextInt(number) will generate a number from interval 0 (inclusive) - number (exclusive).

To start a random activity, you don't need an `Activity` object, all you need is its `Class` object. So create an `ArrayList` as:

```
ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<Class>();
activities.add(SomeActivity.class);

Intent i = new Intent(context, activities.get(random));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What if I use an Array List to create my list of activity? Is it possible to include a class in the Array List? Using its .add function?

Comment: Well is your list defined as ArrayList<Activity> or ArrayList<Class>?

Comment: I want to call the class itself so that i can use its functions.

Comment: tnx for your comments i'll post again when i try what you explain. thank you very much.

Comment: what if i want to shuffle the activities in my ArrayList?

Comment: @user3149781 then use the `Collections.shuffle()` method

Comment: then how can i call the activities? in a new intent?

Comment: for example i have a button where in when i'll press it will load the randomly picked activity in my ArrayList.

Comment: that code above was what i've got so far. it always forces the application to close. do i get what you've explained to me earlier right?

Comment: @user3149781 It just closes? No exceptions or anything?

Comment: it only says that it stops unexpectedly

Comment: @user3149781 That means there's been some Exception.. when you run your app from Eclipse/Android Studio keep the USB cable to your phone connected and then look into LogCat for error messages..